# Dim Picture1 As PictureBox ? Problem with LoadPicture !

Tags: vb6

My **VB6** Code :

```
Dim Picture1 As PictureBox
Picture1.Picture = LoadPicture("D:\1538125064shot.jpg")
```

I am getting the following error on the second line:

> 91 : Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: you need to put a *lot* more effort into your question than that -- what is the exact error you are getting?  If you are not getting an error, are you suppressing it with `On Error Resume Next`?  What is not behaving as expected?  Does the image `D:\1538125064shot.jpg` even exist?

Comment: My Error is : 91 : Object variable or With block variable not set

Answer (score 3):

Your variable is declared as `Picture1`, but you try to access it as `Picture1v`.

Comment: +1 -- Good catch; I wonder if @Faressoft isn't using `Option Explicit`

Comment: sorry i changed this mistake. What is the problem now ?

Comment: Try create the PictureBox using the designer.

Comment: @Faressoft -- according to this thread, you really don't have a choice:  http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=198163.  Either put a PictureBox control on the form, or use `stdPicture`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `StdPicture` to hold pictures before using them

```
Dim myPic As StdPicture
Set myPic = LoadPicture("D:\1538125064shot.jpg")
```

Later you can apply it to a picture box like this

```
Set Picture1.Picture = myPic
```

Comment: I want to compare pixles of 2 imgs without using any tools only vars

Comment: Then you need a `cDIB` class to extract pixels to an array and compare arrays. Search planet-source-code for snippets or try the RichClient toolset from http://www.thecommon.net/